# Jekyll / Bundler fails when creating new default site with `bundle exec jekyll new . --force`

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler

I did `bundle config --global path vendor/bundle` so that Bundler installs dependencies (including Jekyll) to project directories instead of GEM_HOME. I don't have Jekyll installed to GEM_HOME.

When I initialized a project directory...

```
mkdir site && cd site
bundle init
```

Updated the contents of my project Gemfile...

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll"
```

Installed Jekyll to the project directory and created a new site with default scaffolding...

```
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll new . --force
```

...I expected that Jekyll would write the default site scaffolding into the current directory, overwrite *my* original Gemfile, and then `bundle install` default site dependencies from *its* Gemfile (e.g., minima) to vendor/bundle.

Instead, here is the output:

```
Running bundle install in /Users/joeptacek/site...
  Bundler: /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:386:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'minima (~> 2.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:356:in `each'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:356:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:203:in `start'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:182:in `resolve'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:252:in `resolve'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `specs'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:235:in `specs_for'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:224:in `requested_specs'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:100:in `setup'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  Bundler: from /Users/joeptacek/.rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

If I run `bundle install` again, the dependencies are installed without further issue.

To avoid errors, my workaround has been to make a `new` site with

```
bundle exec jekyll new . --force --skip-bundle && bundle install
```

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding something about the way Jekyll and Bundler work?

Comment: followed your steps and I'm unable to reproduce this. But why would you have --force be the default behavior? Are you really in a situation where you want to overwrite a project so often?

Comment: @maxple my project directory contains a Gemfile (i.e., is non-empty), so I need to use --force to initialize jekyll there

Comment: I tried it with the same Gemfile you have shown here. It totally overwrote the Gemfile.

Comment: @maxple thanks for trying to replicate the issue! it overwrites the Gemfile for me too, but then throws errors when it tries to `bundle install` ...not so for you?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the only difference in your workflow from the official documentation is that you install `jekyll` gem and its dependencies to `vendor/bundle`.

`jekyll new` creates a Gemfile along with the site scaffolding. So you needn't initialize one beforehand and then overwrite it with the `--force` switch.

To scaffold a new Jekyll Site at `/projects/site`, you simply need to do the following:

```
# from 'projects/' directory
$ jekyll new site
```

Now you may edit the `Gemfile` and include any other gems as required.

**Note: Its not `bundle exec jekyll new --` but plain ol' `jekyll new`.**
`bundle exec` is **prepended to every other command** only if a `Gemfile` exists within the directory.

Comment: correct, i'm installing jekyll to vendor/bundle using `bundle install`. this is what the original Gemfile is for and why i need to do `bundle exec jekyll new` to create the site. using `jekyll new` wouldn't find jekyll on the $PATH.

Comment: Oh I see.. guess, I misread your question. Can you please report back if you're facing the same issue with `jekyll v3.3.1`? Thanks

Comment: just tried again with jekyll 3.3.1 and got (basically) the same error: "Could not find gem 'minima (~> 2.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems." (as before, following up with another `bundle install` does the trick)